# Spotify API "Request failed with status code 403"

Tags: javascript, react-native, spotify, spotify-app

I'm currently working on a React Native with Expo Go application that tracks Spotify stats using the Spotify API. I was able to successfully set up the authentication process on my iPhone, however, when someone else tries to log in, the app returns an error message stating "Request failed with status code 403".

I added an error handler and discovered that when others try to log in, the app returns the following error:

> "ERROR Forbidden: Insufficient permissions or rate limit exceeded".

I reviewed the Spotify for Developers documentation, but haven't found a solution yet. I would appreciate any help/advice.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (token) {
      axios("https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/top/tracks?time_range=short_term", {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      })
        .then((response) => {
          dispatch(songAction.addTopSongs(response.data.items));
          dispatch(tokenAction.addToken(token));
          navigation.replace("Home", { token: token });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          if (error.response && error.response.status === 403) {
            // Handle 403 error (Forbidden)
            console.error("Forbidden: Insufficient permissions or rate limit exceeded.");
          } else {
            console.error("Error:", error.message);
          }
        });
    }
  }, [token, dispatch, navigation]);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. "When someone else logs in" — how are you obtaining your `token`? What have you tried? See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There are also plenty of Google search results for a query like "403 Spotify API error". Good luck.